# Text Field background color not change it with UI Text Border Style Rounded Rect

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uitextfield, ios4

I am trying to change the background color in IUTextField but I only success if I not set UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect.

```
theTextField.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

I tried to do it within IBuilder and

```
theTextField.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:m_r green:m_g blue:m_b alpha:1.0];
```

It's happened on IOS 4.X not in IOS 5.X
Any idea what could be doing?

Comment: It might be an issue with your post, but first off... `theTextFiels` has a typo. Is that actually there or just an error in the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a sample code and it was working fine to me with all the iOS version >= 3.2

Here is the code

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {

  if ([[textField backgroundColor] isEqual:[UIColor greenColor]]) {

    [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
  }
  else {

    [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

  }
}
```

Here **textField** is an IBOutlet connection which is available in my xib file.

Also added a UIButton which have this action method connected. And It works perfectly for me..

I would suggest you to try a sample with this code.

Comment: Have you tried with borderStyle= UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect